# 0xc000000e error on Windows 10 after disk id change

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I wanted to change the hardware id of my boot drive. However, upon restarting my pc, i got error 0xc000000e: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uljpA.jpg

What I did attempting to change hwid of my boot drive (C:):

- Created Version 4 UUID with https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

  - Suppose I got a93a6e48-b935-47fb-92d6-4bb1fd06bd79
- In regedit, I modified Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\IDConfigDB\Hardware Profiles\0001\HwProfileGuid to {a93a6e48-b935-47fb-92d6-4bb1fd06bd79}
- In regedit, I modified Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\CRYPTOGRAPHY\MachineGuid to a93a6e48-b935-47fb-92d6-4bb1fd06bd79
- Created another Version 4 UUID

  - Suppose I got 9accca61-dbb7-4b6c-9968-347dcd3f0cfd
- In admin CMD, I did the following

  - Diskpart
  - List item
  - select disk 0
  - uniqueid disk id=9accca61-dbb7-4b6c-9968-347dcd3f0cfd
  - bcdedit /default {9accca61-dbb7-4b6c-9968-347dcd3f0cfd}
  - bcdboot c:\windows

I am not sure what I did wrong. How should I make my pc bootable again?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

- Create a Windows installation USB on another computer (if you don't already have one)
- Boot into the Command Prompt
- Undo your changes using the
  [reg command](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)
  (I hope you exported as backup the registry keys you changed).
  Note that you will need to use the REG LOAD command to operate on the registry
  in `d:\windows\system32\config`.
- Reboot.

If this does not help, restore the registry to a previous known good state
by booting to the Command Prompt and entering the following commands:

```
d:
cd d:\windows\system32
mkdir configBak
copy config configBak
cd config\RegBack
copy * ..\*
```

The above is described in detail in the article
[How to restore Registry from its secret backup on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/restore-registry-backup-windows-10/),
so read it well.

Note that the registry backup in the `RegBack` folder might go back too far in time,
so you may lose some settings.
Ensure also that the `RegBack` folder does contain the right files.

Comment: I didn't back up my registry :/

The second solution did not work. doing dir in config\RegBack shows 0 files

Comment: Damn, Microsoft sabotaged it: [The system registry is no longer backed up to the RegBack folder starting in Windows 10 version 1803](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4509719/the-system-registry-is-no-longer-backed-up-to-the-regback-folder-start). It can be turned on, but too late here. Can you boot to [System Restore](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html)? If you can, rollback to a time before you did this change.